# How do I disable built-in index for a model property for GAE?

Tags: django-nonrel, djangoappengine

GAE model properties can be removed from built-in index by setting "indexed" to false.

In DjangoAppEngine, I don't see an API to set model fields to not be indexed. How do I set a model field as such?

Comment: See use of 'unindexed' here: http://djangoappengine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/db.html#indexes

Comment: Perfect, thanks Bernie! If you add your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the excellent documentation you would use 'unindexed' as explained here:
http://djangoappengine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/db.html#indexes

In case you prefer not to follow the link here's a code-sample:

```
from myapp.models import MyContact

FIELD_INDEXES = {
    MyContact: {
        'indexed': [...],
        'unindexed': ['creation_date', 'last_modified', ...],
    },
}
```

Comment: Actually I have one other question, in case you know: If a field is marked unindexed, can it still be included in a composite index?

Comment: I don't know. I kinda doubt it. You should test that assumption of mine out though.

Comment: Thanks, I'm planning to test it.

Comment: Ok, I found out that unindexed property can not be in a composite index. More here: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4231